# Connecting via VCXSRV leads to a blank screen

Tags: xfce, gdm, xdmcp, vcxsrv

When trying to use `vcxsrv` on my laptop I am unable to remotely connect to a Linux system. I just get a blank screen during the remote connection attempt.

I have captured the log file as shown below:

```
Welcome to the VcXsrv X Server
Vendor: The VcXsrv Project
Release: 1.20.14.0

OS: Windows NT 6.2 build 9200 (64-bit)
Contact: marha@users.sourceforge.net

_XSERVTransSocketOpenCOTSServer: Unable to open socket for hyperv
_XSERVTransOpen: transport open failed for hyperv/[REDACTED]:0
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: failed to open listener for hyperv
LoadPreferences: C:\Users\[REDACTED]\AppData\Roaming\.XWinrc not found
LoadPreferences: Loading C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\system.XWinrc
(II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
(II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
```

From the log the issues seems to be related to `hyperv` however I am unsure how to resolve this problem. I am hoping that I am not the only one with this issue.